# HTTP Server in CBuilder

Tags: delphi, c++builder, httpserver

I am a new user in CBuilder Programming. I am writing HTTP Server application, which receives mixed data:both text and a binary data at a time. But I don't know which component and how to use to parse incoming request. My aim is to separate a text data from binary one. Can anybody show examples in Cbuilder or Delphi?

Answer (score 5):

Try using [indy](http://www.indyproject.org/index.en.aspx), check the [`TIdHTTPServer`](http://www.e-iter.net/Knowledge/Indy9/007392.html) component and the `OnCommandGet` event to process the GET, POST, and HEAD requests.